# Unity Main Camera borders are disappearing

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

Sorry for my English. I'm new at game development and unity. I'm watching a tutorial about this. In this tutorial Main Camera borders seems to be like that:
[tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3GqM.jpg)

And this is my 2d project:

[project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLegs.jpg)

And even though this guy select other objects main camera borders don't disappear. But if I select a different object while the main camera is selected, its borders are disappearing like this:

[tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9Bej.jpg)

I searched some settings in the properties of Main Camera but i couldn't find a setting for fix this. How can i fix this?

Comment: check your gizmos in scene view and set camera view is always enable..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Gizmos>Check Camera .
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoCh2.png)

Comment: Actually i had done this. But it's still the same.

Comment: But i found a very useful solution for this. I grabbed the game tab, and dragged it away from the window. Now i can see where are the objects in camera.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, cause accidentally i deleted my Main Camera, you need to check the tags of your camera in the inspector, verify if it's in "MainCamera" tag. :)

[Edit Game tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMW7p.png)